# How to make bot respond to messages randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I wanted to make it to where my bot would randomly respond to messages sent by certain users every so often, I tried searching online to find a way to do this but all I could find was how to send random messages within an array when a command is ran, but that isn't what I want, since I am fairly new to coding I do not know how to do this. in summary, my questions are;

1. How do I make it to where it responds to messages **randomly** from a certain user?
2. Where would I have to put this code since it is not a command?

```
var MessageArray = [
"message 1",
"message 2",
"message 3"
]
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * MessageArray.length);
        try {
          //code to randomly reply to messages sent by a certain user.
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
```

I do not know if this code could be properly used for what I would like the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `random` as the randomly selected index for `MessageArray`

```
var MessageArray = [
   "message 1",
   "message 2",
   "message 3"
];
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * MessageArray.length);
try {
   message.channel.send(MessageArray[random]);
} catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```